# Evaluate A line Integral Via Green's theorem.

Tags: vector-analysis, greens-theorem

Find the value of Line Integral $\int_{C}F.dr$ where $\vec{F} = (x + y)\hat{i} + (1-x)\hat{j}$ where $C$ is the portion of the curve $x^2/4 + y^2/9 = 1$ that is in 4th quadrant with  anti clockwise notation.

Now, using Green's theorem this Line integral is

$\displaystyle \int \int -2 dx dy$ , Since ellipse is symmetric in all quadrants, area in 4th quadrant  = 1/4 area of ellipse,

This gives me $-3\pi$

However, the answer given to me is $5 - 3\pi$

Can anyone tell me the error in my solution  ?

Thank you.

Comment: You’re not integrating over a closed curve, so Green’s theorem isn’t directly applicable.

Comment: you could evaluate the integral on pieces of the negative y axis and positive x axis which are easy line integrals to subtract from the green's double integral